# JQuery Ajax Post - Action returns Partial View but does not hit success or displays

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-ajax

I am making a call to a controller action as follows:

```
$j.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(commentParam),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
        $j('#' + commentsCtrlId + ' ul').prepend(data);
        commentField.val('');
    },
    failure: function () {
        alert("Error adding comment");
    }
});
```

Where the Action looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string commentBody, int parentObjectId, string parentObjectType, int actionId = 0)
    {
        try
        {

        // code to check security and pass info to the database. A comment model object is then passed back to the partial view

            return PartialView("_Comment", comment);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Instance.LogError("Error in CommentController Create", ex);
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

I can break on this method and the data is passed to the database okay.

I can break point on the Partial View so can see the data is being passed there okay, however when I get back to my ajax call, it never gets a response (neither Success or Failure)! I am not getting any errors any where and absolutely nothing to go on. Does anyone have advice on how I can at least try and debug what is going on here please?

Comment: Your method returns a view, so its `dataType: 'html',` not `dataType: 'json',` (your code would be throwing an exception)

Comment: Thank you so much! I havent a lot of experience here but had always assumed this was the type being sent?! Learn something every day. That worked for me though so thank you for such a quick reply.

Comment: If you want to put this as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method returns a view (html), so you need to change the `dataType` option to `'html'`

```
$j.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(commentParam),
    dataType: 'html', // modify
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
```

Note also your method should return a `PartialView` in the `catch` block (as you did for the `try` block)

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Instance.LogError("Error in CommentController Create", ex);
    return PartialView("Error"); // modify
}
```

Comment: yes, absolutely, it was the reason. I was facing same problem, and my datatype was 'json', then i changed it to 'html' according to ur instruction. and it worked perfect. thanks buddy.